# Можно ли поменять местами батарею с уведомлениями?

Tags: android

Уронил телефон и появилось чёрное пятно в правом верхнем углу, закрывает проценты заряда и т. д.

Можно как-то это всё перенести в левый верхний угол?

ОС Андроид 10 mediatek MT6739V/WW

Comment: переместить естественно заряд батареи и т.д

Comment: Какая ОС хоть на телефоне?

Comment: mediatek MT6739V/WW андроид 10